# User location is showing like annotation

Tags: ios, annotations, userlocation

I have multiple Annotation in a `MapView`, listed in 3 different arrays. 
I've used the `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation` method to change te Callout of the annotation.

The weird thing is that my UserLocation is changing into an Customised Annotation.
Why is that, and what could be the problem?

How I listed my Annotations:

```
myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
location.latitude = 52.338847;
location.longitude = 4.937482;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Afvalpunt";
myAnn.subtitle = @"Rozenburglaan 1";
[category3 addObject:myAnn];

[self.locationArrays addObject:category3];

self.currentAnnotation = 0;

[self.myMapView addAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:0]];
```

How my Method is set up:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MapAn"];
    if (!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MapAn"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        //Blauw Navigatie Auto...
        UIImageView *carView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Driving"]];
        UIButton *blueView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44+30)];
        blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:1 alpha:1];
        carView.frame = CGRectMake(11, 14, carView.image.size.width, carView.image.size.height);
        [blueView addTarget:self action:@selector(carClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [blueView addSubview:carView];
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = blueView;
    } 
    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: If you satisfied my answer so please upvote my answer.

Comment: I know man, just 50 sec left ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) return nil;
    ...
```

We return *nil* if the *annotation* is *userLocation* to let the *mapView* display the blue dot & circle animation. In order to show our custom annotation for *userLocation* just remove the line `return nil;` and do your customization there.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

if (!pinView) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
    {
        customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myCarImage.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mySomeOtherImage.png"];
        customPinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        return customPinView;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pinView;
}
```

Hope this code is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
     if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] || annotation==mapView.userLocation)
    {
        return nil;//Here you can also customise your pin if you dont want pin then just return nil.
    }
    else
    {
     //your code
    }
}
```